# Mandatory Field validation not working While creating item in list using Rest api

Tags: validation, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have created a mandatory field in SharePoint online custom list.

While creating an item in the same list using REST API I am allowed to pass a null value.

And the item is created without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue Then as a workaround I applied mandatory field validation through column validation. It works perfectly.

Follow below steps:

1. Go To list settings
2. Click on field that you want as required.
3. Write column validation formula that this field should not be empty (e.g. =**[ColumnName]<>""**) or for null or undefined as well.

Now Again try this validation will work fine for REST API. It will work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much. Rohit Waghela

Comment: Just wanted to ask regarding above formula(e.g. =[ColumnName]<>"") what does it do?

Comment: Hi Rohit i am just stuck with a query related to lookup column also have posted it on stackoverflow below is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988509/not-able-to-get-lookup-field-value-in-sharepoint-2013-online-custom-list-using-s

Comment: Need your help below is the query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48988509/not-able-to-get-lookup-field-value-in-sharepoint-2013-online-custom-list-using-s

Comment: @hiteshramani I have posted on comment on your question. Please reply on that.....

Comment: Hi, I replied. please check

Comment: Hey, I am trying to start a workflow on button click event of a custom button in custom edit form but unable to do it. Could you please guide me on the same.