# Not able to get Lookup field value in Sharepoint 2013 online Custom List Using SPD

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

[image][image]I have one lookup column named **"ActivityStatus"** and it has two values.
and I just want to check that lookup field value on **Presave** Action.
Below is my code but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction() 
{
    alert("Inside");
    var elm = document.getElementById("ActivityStatus");
    alert(elm);
    if (elm == "Incomplete" || elm == "Inprogress")
    {
       document.getElementById("ActivityStatus").style.display='none';
       alert("Previous Activity is in Progress...");
       return false ;
    }
    else
    { 
      return true ;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you share the snippet of your rendered html of your lookup field..

Comment: didnt get your question

Comment: Do you want the screenshot of UI?

Comment: Yes... screenshot of HTML rendered.... (from inspect element)

Comment: I am unable to send SS in a comment.

Comment: Just update/edit your question with the screenshot....

Comment: I meant control whose ID is  `ActivityStatus`...i.e. lookup field....

Comment: Are you getting any value in variable `elm`... And what is the error message you are getting ??

Comment: Yes I am getting [object HTMLSelectElement] in an alert reference to elm variable

Comment: I am using                                                                                             var elm = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl33_g_5afa2bec_2cbb_4abc_afa2_7fbfdeedeaeb_ff121_ctl00_Lookup");

Comment: Have posted SS of HTML for that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are getting lookup value will not work.

you have to do something as below. As it is rendered as a `Select` tag.

Refer below code :

```
function PreSaveAction() 
{

    var elm = document.getElementById("plpace ID your control Here");
    var elmValue = elm.options[elm.elmectedIndex].text.trim();

    if (elmValue == "Incomplete" || elmValue == "Inprogress")
    {
       // 
       //  your other code
       //
    }
    else
    { 
      return true ;
    }
}
```

Here in variable `selectedValue` you will get actual value.

And replace the ID accordingly for your control..

Comment: Rohit Once again you saved me.Thank you very much.

Comment: Just added **var elmValue = elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].text.trim();** What does it acctually do.

Comment: Ok.Got it. Thanks buddy

Comment: Hi Rohit, Need your Help.

Comment: Below is the link to my question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109060/not-able-to-call-java-script-function-on-onclick-event-in-sharepoint-designer

Comment: Hey, I am trying to start a workflow on button click event of a custom button in custom edit form but unable to do it. Could you please guide me on the same.