# Not able to call JavaScript function on onClick Event

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

```
**I have created a custom edit form for a SharePoint online custom list. Where I have created a custom button via which I will start a Workflow.
the issue is I am not able to call that function on button click. I have used a single comma also for the function call
```

I have created a custom edit form for a SharePoint online custom list. Where I have created a custom button via which I will start a Workflow.
  The issue is I am not able to call that function on button click. I have used a single comma also for function call**

HTML Button Code:

```
    <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">

    <input type="button" runat="server" value="Assign To Next Step" name="AssignToNextStep" onClick="startWorkflow()"/>

   </td>
```

JavaScript Function Code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startWorkflow()
{
  alert("Inside");
  try
  {

  showInProgressDialog();

  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

  var wfManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx, ctx.get_web());

  var subscription = wfManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().getSubscription("My Workflow ID");

  ctx.load(subscription, 'PropertyDefinitions');

  ctx.executeQueryAsync(

  function(sender, args)

  {

  wfManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflow(subscription, "");

  ctx.executeQueryAsync(

  function(sender, args)

  {

  closeInProgressDialog();

  },

  function (sender, args)

  {

  closeInProgressDialog();

  alert(errorMessage);

  });

  });

  }

  catch(ex)
  {
  alert(ex);
  dlg.close();
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you saying your startWorkflow() function isn't getting called? Because I just tried it in a codepen and it gets called and I also get the alert that you set at the start. Here is the link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQmBvg

Comment: Yes, I checked it is working perfectly on codepen but not in Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

That Function was out of Scope. I mean I just changed the place of that function.

Answer (score 0):

How do you insert the code? Have you checked the developer tools in your browser if it shows any errors?

Try to add

```
onClick="startWorkflow();return false;"
```

In your code.

Comment: Clarifying questions should best be posted in the comments of the question, not in an answer.